# Objeto não é persistido ao utilizar Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou utilizando o *Entity Framework 6* e o *SqlServer*. Tenho um objeto chamado categoria, onde desejo persistir ele no banco. e quando executo essa função, ele persiste o objeto corretamente pois tenho um *datagrid* onde posso observar que deu certo. Porém quando fecho a aplicação e pesquiso novamente o objeto não está mais lá.

- Porque isso ocorre?
- Ele fica salvo apenas em tempo de execução e não
  persiste?
- Também reparei que o método *SaveChanges* retorna um inteiro, tem
  algo que indique se essa inserção deu certa ou errada? por exemplo,
  se retorna 1 deu certo, caso for 0 errada.

  ```
  private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      categoria objCategoria = new categoria();
  objCategoria.Id = 0;
  objCategoria.descricao = ttbDescricao.Text;
  objCategoria.observacao = ttbObservacao.Text;
  objCategoria.status = 1;

  using (SiscabEntities SisEF = new SiscabEntities())
  {
      //SisEF.categoria.Add(objCategoria);
      if (ttbCodigo.Text.Equals(""))
      {
          SisEF.Entry(objCategoria).State = EntityState.Added;
      }
      else
      {
          SisEF.Entry(objCategoria).State = EntityState.Modified;
      }
      SisEF.SaveChanges();
      Inicializa();
          }
        }
  ```

Comment: Você tem a opção de responder a sua própria pergunta, não coloque como edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O banco de dados local do projeto está na mesma pasta do projeto, sempre quando eu executo o projeto ele joga o banco para o bin/debug criando um novo banco. o que deve ser feito para resolução do problema é ir até as propriedades do arquivo de banco .mdf e alterar o campo 'Alterar para diretorios de saida' e colocar a opção 'Copiar se for mais novo'

Answer (score 1):

boa tarde.
Pelo código postado, falta adicionar o objeto objCategoria na tabela categoria.
Para incluir:

```
SisEF.categoria.Add(objCategoria);
```

Quando for alteração, tem que localizar o registro na tabela e então fazer as atualizações.

```
categoria catAlterada = new categoria();
catAlterada = SisEF.categoria.find(objCategoria.id);
catAlterada = objcategoria;
SisEf.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: na realidade ele esta anexando o objeto no context. da forma que esta funciona se implementado de forma correta.

Answer (score 1):

A forma que você esta tentando fazer é em um senário desconectado, ou seja, seu contexto não tem conhecimento do seu objeto que você esta tentando persistir, então você precisar ensinar o caminha das pedras para ele. 
O primeiro ponto que você precisar alterar é no seu `EntityState.Added;` isso funciona, mas é preciso usar o Attach com seu objeto, o mais simples de se fazer é usar o add.

Outro ponto que você precisar mudar é na edição, você faz instancia de uma categoria, mas não setar o valor do ID nela quando isso for edição vai dar erro.

Veja como você pode esta fazendo nesse senário.

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SiscabEntities SisEF = new SiscabEntities())
    {
        categoria objCategoria = new categoria();
        objCategoria.descricao = ttbDescricao.Text;
        objCategoria.observacao = ttbObservacao.Text;
        objCategoria.status = 1;

        if (ttbCodigo.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            // veja o nome correto  da categoria no seu contexto
            SisEF.Categorias.Add(objCategoria);
        }
        else
        {
            objCategoria.Id = (int)ttbCodigo.Text;
            SisEF.Attach(objCategoria);         
            SisEF.Entry(objCategoria).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        SisEF.SaveChanges();
        Inicializa();
    }
}
```

Um outro senário seria o conectado, nele você teria seu objeto no contexto, ou seja, seu objeto tem todas as propriedade do EF e ele saber o estado atual do seu objeto.

```
private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SiscabEntities SisEF = new SiscabEntities())
    {
        if (!ttbCodigo.Text.Equals(""))
        {           
            var categoria = SisEF.Categorias.Find(1ttbCodigo.Text); // todo convert to int ...
            categoria.descricao = ttbDescricao.Text;
            categoria.observacao = ttbObservacao.Text;
            categoria.status = 1;   
        }   
        else
        {
            categoria objCategoria = new categoria();
            objCategoria.descricao = ttbDescricao.Text;
            objCategoria.observacao = ttbObservacao.Text;
            objCategoria.status = 1;
            SisEF.Categorias.Add(objCategoria);
        }

        SisEF.SaveChanges();
        Inicializa();
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabei de testar os seus dois métodos e o mesmo erro persiste, no começo achei que o erro poderia ser por conta do objeto categoria estar fora do using ... mas nem assim resolve. tenho duas telas uma de cadastro e uma de pesquisa, enquanto o programa está em execução eu consigo cadastrar e visualizar os objetos na tela de pesquisa normalmente, porém quando fecho e abro novamente a aplicação eles desaparecem. inseri alguns itens manualmente no banco, e na tela de pesquisa eles aparecem normalmente.

Comment: Acabei de fazer uma depuração e quando chega no SaveChanges o state está como close

Comment: Isso não poderia estar acontecendo. Vc deve ter algum  dispose implementado em algum lugar. Seu contexto deveria estar em um dos dois estados.  Add ou modificado

Comment: Caso possa me ajudar nessa dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264673/salvando-um-relacionamento-muitos-para-muitos-com-entity-framework