# Salvando um relacionamento muitos para muitos com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Dúvidas ao realizar a inserção de objetos na base de dados ao utilizar o Entity Framework 6 + C# WPF.

tenho 3 objetos OrdemServico, Serviço e os ItensOs. com a seguinte estrutura:

```
public partial class OrdemServico
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public OrdemServico()
    {
        this.ItensOs = new HashSet<ItensOs>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ItensOs> ItensOs { get; set; }
    }
}



public partial class Servico
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Servico()
    {
        this.ItensOs = new HashSet<ItensOs>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorVenda { get; set; }
    public int CategoriaID { get; set; }

    public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ItensOs> ItensOs { get; set; }

    }
}


public partial class ItensOs
{
    public int OrdemServicoID { get; set; }
    public int ServicoID { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public virtual OrdemServico OrdemServico { get; set; }
    public virtual Servico Servico { get; set; }
}
```

Na minha View tenho uma váriavel global do tipo List ItensOs, onde vou armazenando os serviços que foram realizados.

```
ItensOs o = new ItensOs();

o.OrdemServicoID = SeguraServico.Id;
o.Quantidade = Quantidade;
o.ValorUnitario = SeguraServico.ValorVenda;
o.Total = Quantidade * SeguraServico.ValorVenda;

ListaDeServico.Add(o); // Essa é minha váriavel global.
```

Então quando vou salvar isso no banco de dados realizo da seguinte maneira:

```
 using (SiscabEntities SisEF = new SiscabEntities())
 {
      OrdemServico o = new OrdemServico();

      o.Descricao = ttbDescricao.Text;
      o.Data = Convert.ToDateTime(ttbData.Text);
      o.Observacao = "";
      o.Total = AtualizaTotal();
      **//o.ItensOs = ListaDeServico;  <~~ Explicação no final** 

      if (ttbCodigo.Text.Equals("")) 
      { 
           SisEF.OrdemServico.Add(o);
      // Quando você salva o objeto, o proprio savechanges já retorna o Id para o proprio Objeto.
           SisEF.SaveChanges();

           foreach(ItensOs oItens in ListaDeServico)
           {
              oItens.OrdemServicoID = o.Id;
              SisEF.ItensOs.Add(oItens);
           }

      }

      SisEF.SaveChanges();
}
```

Desse jeito eu salvo primeiro minha ordem de serviço e após eu salvo os itens da ordem de serviço. porém ocorre o seguinte erro:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'Unable to update
>   the EntitySet 'ItensOs' because it has a DefiningQuery and no
>    element exists in the 
>   element to support the current operation.'

Minha dúvida é, porque ocorre esse erro? aparentemente não estou utilizando o melhor método de programação mas o algoritmo deveria funcionar.

é possivel salvar meu objeto ListaDeServico na OrderDeServico, e quando eu for salvar ele salva tudo de uma vez? dispensando o foreach? 
**//o.ItensOs = ListaDeServico;  <~~ Explicação no final**

Comment: Se você estive adicionado os seus ItensOs vai precisar setar o OrdemServicoID ai não tem jeito vai ter que fazer o loop mesmo, a não ser que esse valor já venha na sua lista. ai você poderia usar o SisEF.ItensOs.AddRange(oItens); , mas acredito que seu erro seja porque o EF esteja add um objeto que já tem no banco de dados, ou sua propriedade de ID PK não é auto incremento e esteja causando esse erro.

Comment: acredito que essa resposta ajudar ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/7583791/2740371